# How to instantiate class which is returned from a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function `classGenerator` which returns a class `Klass`.

```
export const classGenerator = () => {
  return class Klass extends React.Component {
    //....
  }
}
```

How can I now instantiate `Klass` inside a function somewhere else? I've tried a number of things, such as:

```
import { classGenerator } from "./class_generator"

function App() {
  return(
    {/* This syntax here is incorrect */}
    <{classGenerator()} />
  )
}
```

But all my attempts have failed, since my syntax is most likely incorrect.

Comment: You can change your classGenerator to return instance of Klass component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
const Test = classGenerator();
...
<Test/>
```